# Add multiple interceptors for different endpoint in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, interceptor, okhttp

To return mock JSON data for my retrofit endpoints, I've created a custom Interceptor and added it to the OkHttpClient for Retrofit like this: `client.addInterceptor(new HttpInterceptor());`

The implementation I've created works fine, but it's not very scalable. All the endpoints and their mock data are handled in a single file like this:

```
public class HttpInterceptor implements Interceptor {
private static final int TEST_QUANTITY = 10;

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

    Response response;
    String responseString;
    String uriPath = chain.request().url().uri().getPath();
    if (uriPath.equalsIgnoreCase("/geofences")) {
        responseString = buildMockGeofences(TEST_QUANTITY);
    } else if (uriPath.equalsIgnoreCase("/retailers")) {
        responseString = buildMockRetailers(TEST_QUANTITY);
    } else if (uriPath.equalsIgnoreCase("/products")) {
        responseString = buildMockProducts(TEST_QUANTITY);
    } else if (uriPath.matches("/retailers/(\\d+)")) {
        String stringId = uriPath.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(stringId);
        responseString = getRetailer(id);
    } else if (uriPath.matches("\\/products\\/\\w+")) {
            String id =  uriPath.substring(uriPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            responseString = getProduct(id);
    } else if (uriPath.matches("/geofences/(\\d+)")) {
        String stringId = uriPath.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        int id = Integer.parseInt(stringId);
        responseString = getGeofence(id);
    } else {
        responseString = "{}";
    }
    response = new Response.Builder()
            .code(200)
            .message(responseString)
            .request(chain.request())
            .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_0)
            .body(ResponseBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), responseString.getBytes()))
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
            .build();
    return response;
}

private String buildMockProducts(int testQuantity) {
    String jsonProducts = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= testQuantity; i++) {
        jsonProducts += "{\"_id\" : \" " + i + " \" , " +
                "\"name\" : \"Product" + i + "\" , " +
                "\"category\" : \"category\" , " +
                "\"requiredStamps\" :  " + i + " , " +
                "\"size\" : \"n.a.\" , " +
                "\"price\" : \"€15,-\" , " +
                "\"description\" : \"description\" , " +
                "\"stickerId\" :  \"" + stickerIds().get(i) + "\"  }";
        if (i != testQuantity)
            jsonProducts += ",";
    }
    return "[" + jsonProducts + "]";
}

private List<String> stickerIds() {
    List<String> stickerIdList = new ArrayList<>();
    stickerIdList.add(null);
    stickerIdList.add("0798e8199c4fbbaa");
    stickerIdList.add("496fa572b8a2e03d");
    stickerIdList.add("4a1d5cdd6b0764f5");
    stickerIdList.add("3deac01afb311b13");
    stickerIdList.add("9ee2a14a92025ace");
    stickerIdList.add("494e443257a4dd95");
    stickerIdList.add("fa3dd8e30c872245");
    stickerIdList.add("5c81ccfc21dedb74");
    stickerIdList.add("0b642e5658453ce1");
    stickerIdList.add("9d0c9aa50f971cd7");
    return stickerIdList;
}

private String getProduct(String id) {
    return  "{\"_id\" : \" " + id + " \" , " +
            "\"name\" : \"Product\" , " +
            "\"category\" : \"category\" , " +
            "\"requiredStamps\" :  " + 25 + " , " +
            "\"size\" : \"n.a.\" , " +
            "\"price\" : \"€15,-\" , " +
            "\"description\" : \"description\" , " +
            "\"stickerId\" :  \"" + id + "\"  }";
}


private String buildMockRetailers(int numberOfRetailers) {
    String jsonRetailers = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfRetailers; i++) {
        jsonRetailers += "{\"_id\" : \" " + i + " \" , " +
                "\"name\" : \"Retailer Name " + i + "\" , " +
                "\"street\" : \"straatnaam\" , " +
                "\"housenumber\" : \" " + i + " \" , " +
                "\"postalCode\" : \"1023BH\" , " +
                "\"city\" : \"City\" , " +
                "\"geofence\" :  \"" + i + "\"  }";
        if (i != numberOfRetailers)
            jsonRetailers += ","; // don't add closing comma
    }
    return "[" + jsonRetailers + "]";
}

private String getRetailer(int id) {
    return "[{\"_id\" : \" " + id + " \" , " +
            "\"name\" : \"Retailer Name " + id + "\" , " +
            "\"street\" : \"straatnaam\" , " +
            "\"housenumber\" : \" " + id + " \" , " +
            "\"postalCode\" : \"1023BH\" , " +
            "\"city\" : \"City\" , " +
            "\"geofence\" : \"" + id + "\" }]";
}

private String getGeofence(int id) {
    return "[{\"_id\" : \" " + id + " \" , " +
            "\"title\" : \"TEST_GEOFENCE" + id + "\" , " +
            "\"latitude\" : " + genRandLatitude() + " , " +
            "\"longitude\" : " + genRandLongitude() + " , " +
            "\"radius\" : 500 , " +
            "\"retailer\" : \"" + id + "\"  }]";
}

private String buildMockGeofences(int numberOfGeofences) {
    String jsonGeofences = "";
    for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfGeofences; i++) {
        jsonGeofences += "{\"_id\" : \"58ca9bc5384ec0172c94423" + i + "\" , " +
                "\"title\" : \"TEST_GEOFENCE" + i + "\" , " +
                "\"latitude\" : " + genRandLatitude() + " , " +
                "\"longitude\" : " + genRandLongitude() + " , " +
                "\"radius\" : 500 , " +
                "\"retailer\" : \"" + i + "\"  }";
        if (i != numberOfGeofences)
            jsonGeofences += ",";
    }
    return "[" + jsonGeofences + "]";
}

private double genRandLatitude() {
    Random r = new Random();
    double randomValue = 52.322632 + (52.397274 - 52.322632) * r.nextDouble();
    return Math.floor(randomValue * 1000000) / 1000000;
}

private double genRandLongitude() {
    Random r = new Random();
    double randomValue = 4.845314 + (4.952431 - 4.845314) * r.nextDouble();
    return Math.floor(randomValue * 1000000) / 1000000;
}
```

How do I add multiple interceptors to the httpclient of Retrofit? Because if I simply seperate the logic like this:

`client.addInterceptor(new GeofenceHttpInterceptor());
client.addInterceptor(new RetailerHttpInterceptor());
client.addInterceptor(new ProductHttpInterceptor());`

It will still intercept the url's in the first interceptor. Any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: In your Interceptor that can't handle such-and-such path, simply return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build()).

Comment: An alternative solution might be to use Retrofit mock to cleanly mock the server responses: https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-mock

Comment: thx, @EricCochran it's working! And maybe i'll take a look at the retrofit mock